# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable for API in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to coding and I'm making a discord bot that accesses an API but a specific feature i'm working on is not working at all, In the api everything shows like this and this is all thats there,

```
    [{imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/F06C5733_large.png", manifestId: 5733,…},…]
0: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/F06C5733_large.png", manifestId: 5733,…}
1: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/7F34984_large.png", manifestId: 984,…}
2: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/E6B6417_large.png", manifestId: 417,…}
3: {,…}
4: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/845E743_large.png", manifestId: 743,…}
5: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/3E9F5241_large.png", manifestId: 5241,…}
6: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/9C766302_large.png", manifestId: 6302,…}
7: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/65696303_large.png", manifestId: 6303,…}
8: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/25A56304_large.png", manifestId: 6304,…}
9: {imageUrl: "https://cdn.thetrackernetwork.com/cdn/fortnite/BBB66307_large.png", manifestId: 6307,…}
```

as you can see its a list and not a dict I think so I can't use the same code as my other command since thats a dict

```
  if req.status_code == 200:
    try:
      print(req.json())
      lifetime_stats = req.json()['lifeTimeStats']
      return lifetime_stats[0:]
    except KeyError:
      return False
  else:
    return False
```

the code im trying to use for this one is

```
  if req.status_code == 200:
    try:
      print(req.json())
      storefront_catalog = req.json()[0]
      return storefront_catalog()
    except KeyError:
      return False
  else:
    return False
```

I kept getting the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when I was trying to make the end of req.json a string so I made it a number and took away the number from `return storefront_catalog` and now its searching the api and showing it all in the console but then giving the error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

I probably said a few things wrong here as I said I'm pretty new to coding and python.

Thanks to anyone that helps

Comment: `storefront_catalog()` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Learning by guessing is very time-consuming. Consider picking up an introductory book.

Comment: Make a discord embed to show each of those each of those expanded each one in a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess but it looks like your latest error is the result of doing `return storefront_catalog()`. Since, at this point, `storefront_catalog` is not a callable object but a dictionary, you can't call it like a method. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this return statement but if you want to "make it work", you could try doing `return storefront_catalog` instead. As an aside, I would suggest making use of the `type` method as a preliminary step when debugging code. This will tell you what type you're working with and should help you figure out where you're going wrong. You could call it with `print` like this:

```
print(type(storefront_catalog))
```